# Connect to Redshift using Zeppelin

Tags: amazon-redshift, apache-zeppelin

Problem:

1. Can't connect to Redshift using Zeppelin. When I try to connect I get the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:redshiftl://redshift_db_address.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/db_name

Background:

1. I am using the dylanmei/zeppelin docker image.
2. I created the Redshift interpreter according to the instructions here: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/interpreter/jdbc.html#redshift
3. I downloaded this JDBC driver: https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar 
   --> `installed to /usr/zeppelin/interpreter/jdbc/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar`
4. Set the artifact path to: `com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-redshift:1.11.51`
5. Set driver.default to: `com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver`

Comment: in `jdbc: jdbc:redshiftl` what is `l`? i mean, the last char of `redshiftl`

Comment: facepalm....that was the issue - thanks.

Comment: Christopher how did you know you had to do Step 3. ? I don't see it in the documentation.

Comment: @Hugo - I went here: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/interpreter/jdbc.html#redshift, then I clicked the 'AWS Redshift JDBC Driver Docs' link - it describes how to download JDBC driver.

Comment: Thank you Christopher, the part not obvious to me was that the driver had to be placed in /zeppelin/interpreter/jdbc/ . Glad you wrote this question.